# Right-align a <p> within a <div> WITHOUT using floats

Tags: css

I have a single line with 1 icon and 2 pieces of text - I would like to display the right-most piece of text on the far right of the line, with the other items aligned left.

I'm trying to keep the code as lean as possible so I'd like to see if this can be done **without using floats**, **without wrapping each `<p>` in a `<div>` of its own** and also **without JS** (which is why I couldn't find an appropriate answer from similar questions asked on here).

Here's the JSFiddle, I'd like to have the word **Break** displayed on the far right of the line and *have the task take up the rest of the width of the containing div*:
**http://jsfiddle.net/2w1cu71e/**

Thank you in advance for any help you might be able to give me, I'm finding it a bit hard to find definitive resources on CSS best practices (aside from CSS Tricks!).
Ines

Comment: I was hoping [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) would be the answer but I couldn't find a way to align an _individual_ item within the container to the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using `<p>` tag there doesn't make sense, `<span>` would be better for doing the job. For the layout I think CSS `table table-row table-cell` can be a good option over flexbox, and it works on all browsers.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/2w1cu71e/1/

```
#done {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.desc-single-line {
    display: table-row;
}
.desc-single-line i,
.desc-single-line span {
    display: table-cell;
}
.desc-single-line i {
    width: 20px;
}
.desc-single-line span {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
.desc-single-line .task-category {
    color: red;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You only need to add `position:absolute;right:0;` to `.task-category` but this markup might be made far simpler if you don't have a reason to be using the `<p>` elements at all.

All-in-all, I don't see the difference to using a float. There's also the question as to why the `<p>` is an inline-block but you have your reasons.

Comment: I was mostly using <p> because I find <span>s incredibly un-semantic but I'm still learning! What would you say is best practice?

Comment: @iteles As the spec says, a span element doesn't mean anything on its own. For that matter, using the <p> element is not semantic either because the text you show aren't paragraphs; just a short phrase. Not using a <p> element at all would be just as good unless it messes up your structure or styling. Text does not need to be inside a <p> element just because it's text. Use spans to style something without concern for semantics because span is a generic container.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this instead of the CSS provided? For some reason it doesn't work on jsfiddle but it works just fine on a local html file.

```
.desc-single-line {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.task-category{
    color:red;
    text-align: right;
    flex: 2;
}

.desc-single-line p{
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```